Gparted doesn't allow adding free space to partition at end of table
I've dual booted my Ubuntu 22.04 system with a Windows 10. I alloted 100GB initially, but that turned out to be just slightly less than I thought I needed. Now I'm trying to increase the size of my Windows partition by using GParted from a Live Ubuntu, but I'm unable to add the free space to the windows partition.
Screenshot of GParted:

As shown in the above image, I reduced the size of my Ubuntu partition (nvme0n1p2) so as to use that free space in my windows partition (nvme0n1p4), but I'm unable to add that free space to Windows. Can anyone help me with this?
I've checked similar questions before posting this, but none of them match my situation.
Edit (adding some context) - When I right click on the partition nvme0n1p3, all the options are greyed out (except New and properties). This renders me unable to move the free space to the end and add it to nvme0n1p4.

Delete the MSR partition, then recreate it when booted to Windows - this is why the first two partitions should always be EFI, MSR, followed by all other partitions, with WinRE being the very last partition (which you lack and should exist)

Make sure to create a backup copy before moving a partition. It is a high-risk operation.

@JW0914 I've tried to dual boot windows on an existing Ubuntu machine, hence the MSR partition is after EFI and the disk space I kept for Ubuntu. Also, the Windows OS works perfectly fine despite not having a WinRE partition. Is it absolutely necessary? Did I mess up teh setup somehow?

It would be recommended to move the MSR partition after the EFI partition - the reason why is because when partitions are resized, free space is taken from the end of the partition, which can create issues when these two unchanging partitions are placed in a different order, as well as taking more time for a resize. WinRE is required because if Windows fails to boot, WinRE is needed to correct the issue (as well as to image the OS partition with Dism)
